# Exporting database from SQL Server to Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I'm trying export (with the export tool of SQLServer).
The process ended with errors, because all the tables has the follow error:

```
Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  
The "input "Destination Input" (194)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, 
and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (194)" specifies failure on error. 
An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  
An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  
Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Tables without a clustered index are not 
supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and 
try again.".
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure whether this is considered on-topic here or not, but you might have more luck checking on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), since I imagine they have at least as much experience doing things like this as we do.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I'd imagine more luck would be on DBA Stack. But the issue is trivial if you read the error message carefully (See my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says that you don't have a clustered index on one of the tables:

```
"Tables without a clustered index are not 
supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and 
try again."
```

[SQL Azure requires that every table has a clustered index](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/04/29/10004618.aspx) and tables without the index can not be created in Azure.

So you'll have to check your existing database that all your tables have a clustered index. And for the ones that don't have it, create it. Then try to export to SQL Azure again.

Run this command to add a clustered index to a table:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Table1_Index ON Table1 (Col1)
```

The reason for this requirement is for data replication. In order to replicate data effectively across different servers, tables must have a proper ordering of data pages in binary-tree structure. And without clustered index (in heap tables) replication becomes a nightmare. See more details in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/12/10011257.aspx)

And [here is the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336245.aspx#cir) of SQL Azure restrictions

Comment: I have added indexes to my local SQL Server database, but I still get the error when exporting to Azure SQL. It seems like the indexes does not follow when the table structure is exported, hence it fails when the data is added.
Anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Comment: @MatsMagnem how do you move local table to Azure? When you create the DB in Azure, can you check if indexes are indeed there before adding data?

Answer (score 0):

First, generate table script without applying any indexing from local and run on azure. Then, apply clustered indexing. It will work.